# SQL: how do I maintain a running total that resets after reaching a certain threshold?

Tags: sql, function, window, amazon-redshift

if I have a simple table that has a person ID and a date, and many rows per person with different dates, how can I track how many days passed from one date to the next, and reset the count once I reach a certain threshold?  I have at least got the running total part working (using sum over window function), but if I want to note when it reaches 10 days, I cannot figure out how to reset the counter. I am working in Redshift. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

For some specific context on the use case, I have a table with medical events and if a person has another event within 10 days of the initial event, I want to not count subsequent events in the 10 day window as a separate event, but once I have found an event that is greater than 10 days after the initial event, I want to count that one as a second event, and so on.

```
Person A, day 1, mark as new event
Person A, day 5, do not mark as new event
Person A, day 12, mark as new event
Person A, day 15, do not mark as new event
Person A, day 23, mark as new event
Person A, day 100, mark as new event
```

Thank you. Perhaps this will help? The input table would be:

```
person_id   day
A       1
A       5
A       12
A       15
A       23
A       100
```

And the desired result would be:

```
person_id   day     new_event
A       1   1
A       5   0
A       12  1
A       15  0
A       23  1
A       100 1
```

Comment: Providing a sanple table in the form of a `create table` and `insert into` statements would be useful.

Comment: This problem requires hierarchical or recursive queries, which RedShift does not support.